# Prevent deb installation from creating new accounts

Tags: users, dpkg, useradd, accounts, uid

We are configuring a variety of servers programmatically, and we periodically need to be able to migrate volumes from one server to another. After migrating a volume, we are currently executing `chown` commands to ensure proper ownership after the migration, since different systems may allocate different UIDs to the same username.

To simplify our migrations and make them as fast as possible (no more `chown -R` on huge directories), we would like to ensure that users receive consistent UIDs on all systems. To achieve this, we're planning to enumerate all of the users we expect to exist on our systems, allocating their UIDs ourselves. With that, we can programmatically create those users with stable UIDs.

As our server configurations change over time, and as we keep our Ubuntu environments up to date, it's inevitable that new user accounts will be introduced to our servers, many of them auto-created by `dpkg`. Is there any straightforward way to instead cause these attempted user account creations to error out so that we can add them to our user enumeration?

I'd love to read any resources about this topic that share best practices. My searching so far has been fruitless.

Comment: Prior to running `apt upgrade` you could replace `/sbin/useradd` with `/bin/true`. That will prevent upgrade scripts from adding any users accounts.

Comment: ... and cause the maintainer scripts to fail in unobvious ways, making it difficult to complete the upgrade.